# Undefined PHP Variable with PDO

Tags: php

PHP is giving errors such as

> rowCount() is an non-object reference ...

The code worked a few hours earlier, then stopped working and getting these errors out of the blue...

Any ideas on what caused PHP to start giving random errors?

```
   $query = $db->query("QUERY HERE")->rowCount();
```

PDO -- PHP5

> Can I also point out that, this code worked BEFORE then it just randomly broke with no editing or anything... php just gave up!

Comment: Your database server has stopped responding ... test the connection object before sending queries

Comment: @Orangepill: or the query is syntactically incorrect

Comment: @zerkms I think you're right ... it's not barfing with connection errors ... its barfing on $query not being an object errors

Comment: how do you pass params to query?

Comment: That error message doesn't exist. Did you mean "calling `rowCount()` on a non-object"? Also, enable exception handling; `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: I know everyone does it because PDO_MySQL supports `rowCount()` on select queries (for now) but you should *really* read the advice here - http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.rowcount.php#example-1038

Comment: Also, for compatibility it's not recommended to use `->rowCount()` on SELECT queries. Basically, what @Phil said :)

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, I accidently deleted my users table without notice. x3

Answer (score -1):

check this

```
$query = $db->query("QUERY HERE");

$count = $query->rowCount();
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as what I had with 1 more line.